# Why is second harmonic Intensity periodic in coherent length?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, phase-space, non-linear-optics, harmonics

Solving for the intensity of second harmonic generation we get that intensity is $sinc^2(\pi/2*L/L_{coherent})$.

How is calculated that the intensity is periodic in L_{coherent} (coherent length, L medium length).

I am totally confused here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note it is not *exactly* periodic, it only touches zeros for some equally spaced values of L, but its maxima become lower with decreasing coherence length. Note also you are using the non-depleted-pump approximation.

The evolution of the SHG wave is determined by two factors when propagating through the nonlinear medium - it gains energy from the pump wave, and simultaneously it also goes out of sync in phase with it.

For a slight difference of the effective indices for both waves, the phase difference is negligible and SHG signal is strong. For a larger difference of phase, it will reverse the energy flow and the SHG wave eventually returns its energy to the pump - this is the first minimum of the sinc² function.

For even larger difference the process is gain-return-gain, but the gain region is shorter. This explains the pseudo-oscillating nature of the sinc² function, and also the fact its maxima get lower and lower with increasing index difference.